# Minimax algorithm not working in tic tac toe game

Tags: python-3.x, minimax

I have recently learned about minimax and I am trying to make an unbeatable AI tic tac toe game. I don't know why my minimax function does not work and my computer sometime plays un optimal moves.

This is my full code:

```
from random import randint
import os

def play_again():
    print()
    t=True
    while t:
        p=input("Do you want to play again? Y or N  ").upper()
        if p=='Y' or p=='YES':
            t=False
            return True
        elif p=='N' or p=='NO':
            t=False
            print("Thank You!!")
            return False
        else:
            print('Enter a valid input!')
            
    
        
while True:

    board1=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
    print('    |   |')
    print(' ',board1[0],'|',board1[1],'|',board1[2])
    print('____|___|____')
    print('    |   |')
    print(' ',board1[3],'|',board1[4],'|',board1[5])
    print('____|___|____')
    print('    |   |')
    print(' ',board1[6],'|',board1[7],'|',board1[8])
    print('    |   |')

    
    board=[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
    def print_board():
        
        print('    |   |')
        print(' ',board[0],'|',board[1],'|',board[2])
        print('____|___|____')
        print('    |   |')
        print(' ',board[3],'|',board[4],'|',board[5])
        print('____|___|____')
        print('    |   |')
        print(' ',board[6],'|',board[7],'|',board[8])
        print('    |   |')


    if randint(0,1)==0:
        player='Player 1'
    else:
        player='Player 2'


    a='a'
    while a not in ['X','O']:
        a=input("Player 1: Do you want to be X or O: ").upper()
            
        if a not in ['X','O']:
            print("Enter valid output X or O")

    if a=='X':
        c='O'
    else:
        c='X'

    def first():
        if player=='Player 1':
            print()
            print('Player 1 will go first')
            
        else:
            print()
            print('Player 2 will go first')
            
    first()

    def position_check():
        return board[b-1] not in ['X','O']

    def board_full():
        for i in board:
            if i not in ['X','O']:
                return True
        return False


    def win_check(m):
        return ((board[0]==m and board[1]==m and board[2]==m) or
                (board[3]==m and board[4]==m and board[5]==m) or
                (board[6]==m and board[7]==m and board[8]==m) or
                (board[0]==m and board[3]==m and board[6]==m) or
                (board[1]==m and board[4]==m and board[7]==m) or
                (board[2]==m and board[5]==m and board[8]==m) or
                (board[0]==m and board[4]==m and board[8]==m) or
                (board[2]==m and board[4]==m and board[6]==m))

    def minimax(board,depth,ismax):
        
        if win_check(c):
            return 1

        elif win_check(a):
            return -1

        elif not board_full:
            return 0

        if ismax:
            bestscore = -1000

            for i in range(len(board)):
                
                if board[i]==' ':
                    board[i]=c
                    score= minimax(board,depth+1,False)
                    
                    board[i]=' '

                    if score > bestscore:
                        bestscore = score

            return bestscore

        else:
            bestscore = 1000

            for i in range(len(board)):
                if board[i]==' ':
                    
                    board[i]=a

                    score= minimax(board,depth+1,True)
                    
                    board[i]=' '

                    if score < bestscore:
                        bestscore = score

            return bestscore
            
        
    while board_full():
        
        if player=='Player 1':
            b='a'
            within_range=False
            while b.isdigit()==False or within_range==False:
                b=input("Enter your next move (1-9) :")

                if b.isdigit()==False:
                    print('\n'*100)
                    print('Enter a choice between 1-9')

                if b.isdigit()==True:
                    if int(b) in range(1,10):
                        within_range=True
                    else:
                        print('Enter a choice between 1-9')

            b=int(b)

            if position_check():
                board[b-1]=a
                print_board()
                if win_check(a):
                    print('Congratulations Player 1 wins!!')
                    break
                else:
                    player='Player 2'

            else:
                print('Position already occupied')

        if player=='Player 2':

            bestscore = -1000

            for i in range(len(board)):
                if board[i]==' ':
                    board[i]=c

                    score= minimax(board,0,False)
                    
                    board[i]=' '

                    if score > bestscore:
                        bestscore = score
                        bestmove=i
                        b=bestmove

            if position_check:
                
                board[b]=c
                
                print_board()
                
                if win_check(c):
                    print('Congratulations Player 2 wins!!')
                    break
                else:
                    player='Player 1'
                    
                


    else:
        print('Its a DRAW!!')


    if not play_again():
        break
```

When I play position 1 comp should play position 5 but it doesn't but it always plays position 2 and eventually looses Where is the mistake in my code
I just learned about minimax and I don't want to use depth concept :

```
    |   |
  1 | 2 | 3
____|___|____
    |   |
  4 | 5 | 6
____|___|____
    |   |
  7 | 8 | 9
    |   |
Player 1: Do you want to be X or O: x

Player 1 will go first
Enter your next move (1-9) :1
    |   |
  X |   |  
____|___|____
    |   |
    |   |  
____|___|____
    |   |
    |   |  
    |   |
    |   |
  X | O |  
____|___|____
    |   |
    |   |  
____|___|____
    |   |
    |   |  
    |   |
```

Comment: So what have you done to debug? Did you use a debugger and set break points? Inspect variables? Step through? What was the outcome? What was the first statement where things didn't go as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues:

- In `minimax` at this statement:

  ```
  elif not board_full:
  ```

  This condition is never fulfilled, because you are evaluating the function object, not the result from *calling* the function.

  This should be:

  ```
  elif not board_full():
  ```

  I should say that the name of this function is misleading. `board_full` returns True when the board is **not** full, despite its name. You would better call it differently, like: `board_has_moves`.
- There's a similar problem in the second half of the main loop, where you have:

  ```
        if position_check:
  ```

  This condition is always true, even when the game is over, and so the computer gets to play their last iterated move (i.e. 9) -- overwriting that cell with an invalid move.

  It should have the parentheses.
- The function `position_check` apparently expects a 1-based value of `b`, as it works with `b-1`, but the computer move is stored in `b` as a 0-based value. So `position_check` will not work correctly with that. I suggest that you work with a 0-based `b` value all the way, and adapt `position_check` to work with `b` instead of `b-1`. The human player's move can be set correctly by doing `b=int(b) - 1`
- If the human player had played the last possible move, then still the second `if` block is entered *without first checking whether the game is over!*. If all of the above fixes have been implemented, this will still work out ok, but it is better to make that `if player=='Player 2':` an `else:` statement. That way the main loop will only execute one of the two blocks -- never both in the same iteration.

Not a problem, but:

- Choose good names. Names like `a`, `b` and `c` are meaningless and make the code harder to read. It is much clearer if you name those `player_1_symbol`, `move`, `player_2_symbol`
- In `play_again` you don't need the name `t`. Just do a `while True:`.
- It is disturbing that you have defined functions in a loop's body! Don't do that. Move them outside the loop. This means that for `position_check` and other functions, you should to pass some values as a function argument -- which anyway is good practice.
- I would put the move-loop in a separate function, and that function could have local function(s): I would actually only define `minimax` as a local function, so the number of arguments can be kept small for this recursive function.
- Avoid the use of global variables, and also put the main logic in a function, like `main()`. This makes the names that were global into local names and forces you to pass arguments -- which is good practice.

There is certainly much more to improve, but the above changes (and a few more), led to this version of your code:

```
from random import randint

def play_again():
    print()
    while True:
        p=input("Do you want to play again? Y or N  ").upper()
        if p=='Y' or p=='YES':
            return True
        elif p=='N' or p=='NO':
            print("Thank You!!")
            return False
        else:
            print('Enter a valid input!')

def print_board(board):  # parameter list
    print('    |   |')
    print(' ',board[0],'|',board[1],'|',board[2])
    print('____|___|____')
    print('    |   |')
    print(' ',board[3],'|',board[4],'|',board[5])
    print('____|___|____')
    print('    |   |')
    print(' ',board[6],'|',board[7],'|',board[8])
    print('    |   |')

def first(player):  # argument list
    print()
    if player=='Player 1':
        print('Player 1 will go first')
    else:
        print('Player 2 will go first')
        
def position_check(board, move):
    return board[move] not in ['X','O']

def board_has_moves(board):
    for i in board:
        if i not in ['X','O']:
            return True
    return False

def win_check(board, m):
    return ((board[0]==m and board[1]==m and board[2]==m) or
            (board[3]==m and board[4]==m and board[5]==m) or
            (board[6]==m and board[7]==m and board[8]==m) or
            (board[0]==m and board[3]==m and board[6]==m) or
            (board[1]==m and board[4]==m and board[7]==m) or
            (board[2]==m and board[5]==m and board[8]==m) or
            (board[0]==m and board[4]==m and board[8]==m) or
            (board[2]==m and board[4]==m and board[6]==m))

# A function to deal with one game
def playgame(board, player, player_1_symbol, player_2_symbol):
    def minimax(depth, ismax):  # removed board parameter, as already in scope
        if win_check(board, player_2_symbol):  # pass board also
            return 1
        elif win_check(board, player_1_symbol):
            return -1
        elif not board_has_moves(board):  # call it, rename it
            return 0
        if ismax:
            bestscore = -1000
            for i in range(len(board)):
                if board[i]==' ':
                    board[i]=player_2_symbol
                    score= minimax(depth+1,False)
                    board[i]=' '
                    if score > bestscore:
                        bestscore = score
            return bestscore
        else:
            bestscore = 1000
            for i in range(len(board)):
                if board[i]==' ':
                    board[i]=player_1_symbol
                    score= minimax(depth+1,True)
                    board[i]=' '
                    if score < bestscore:
                        bestscore = score
            return bestscore
    
    while board_has_moves(board):  # better name; pass argument
        if player=='Player 1':
            move='a'  # better name
            within_range=False
            while not move.isdigit() or not within_range:
                move=input("Enter your next move (1-9) :")
                if not move.isdigit():
                    print('\n'*100)
                    print('Enter a choice between 1-9')
                if move.isdigit():
                    if int(move) in range(1,10):
                        within_range=True
                    else:
                        print('Enter a choice between 1-9')
            move=int(move)-1  # reduce to make it 0-based
            if position_check(board, move):  # pass the arguments
                board[move]=player_1_symbol   # b is zero based now
                print_board(board)  # pass argument
                if win_check(board, player_1_symbol):  # pass arguments
                    print('Congratulations Player 1 wins!!')
                    break
                else:
                    player='Player 2'
            else:
                print('Position already occupied')
        else:  # changed to avoid code falling thru from the previous block
            bestscore = -1000
            bestmove = 10  # better initialise before loop
            for i in range(len(board)):
                if board[i]==' ':
                    board[i]=player_2_symbol
                    score= minimax(0,False)
                    board[i]=' '
                    if score > bestscore:
                        bestscore = score
                        bestmove=i
            if position_check(board, bestmove):  # add the parentheses to call it
                board[bestmove]=player_2_symbol
                print_board(board)  # pass argument
                if win_check(board, player_2_symbol):
                    print('Congratulations Player 2 wins!!')
                    break
                else:
                    player='Player 1'
    else:
        print('Its a DRAW!!')


# Main program
def main():  # avoid global variables, and put main logic in a function
    while True:
        board1=['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
        print('    |   |')
        print(' ',board1[0],'|',board1[1],'|',board1[2])
        print('____|___|____')
        print('    |   |')
        print(' ',board1[3],'|',board1[4],'|',board1[5])
        print('____|___|____')
        print('    |   |')
        print(' ',board1[6],'|',board1[7],'|',board1[8])
        print('    |   |')
        board=[' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ']
    
        # simplified:
        player = ('Player 1', 'Player 2')[randint(0,1)]
        player_1_symbol ='a'  # better name
        while player_1_symbol not in ['X','O']:
            player_1_symbol=input("Player 1: Do you want to be X or O: ").upper()
            if player_1_symbol not in ['X','O']:
                print("Enter valid output X or O")
        # use ternary operator, and use better name
        player_2_symbol = 'O' if player_1_symbol=='X' else 'X'
        first(player)  # pass argument
        # move the move-loop logic into another function:
        playgame(board, player, player_1_symbol, player_2_symbol)
        if not play_again():
            break
    
main()
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. You solved a great problem of mine. I am still a beginner in Python and I will definitely implement your suggestions in my future project.